# How to shutdown server socket after 60s in C

Tags: c, sockets

I want to listen for incoming connections for 60 sec than shutdown my server socket. How can I do it?

Comment: Sleep for 60 seconds, then set some 'shutdown' boolean and connect to the server to make the accept() call return.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting in `accept` for a connection, use `select` or `poll` to wait for the socket to become readable, which indicates that there's a connection to accept. You can have `select` or `poll` time out after 60s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select with a timeout on a socket marked for reading in descriptor set. You can also set alarm signal using alarm():

```
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int alarm(unsigned int seconds);
```